# systemd instance name (%i) not working in ExecStart

Tags: systemd

For some reason, systemd is not replacing `%i` or `%I` with the instance name in ExecStart

---

/systemd/system/service/foo@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo service for %I

[Service]
User=keith
ExecStart=/path/to/foo/%i/food
...
```

---

/path/to/foo/bar/food

```
#/bin/bash

node /path/to/foo/bar/bard.js
```

---

Then I run:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start foo@bar
$ sudo systemctl status foo@bar
● foo@bar.service - Foo service for bar
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/foo@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-09-30 19:07:02 EDT; 6s ago
  Process: 18705 ExecStart=/path/to/foo/%i/food (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 18705 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 30 19:07:02 kptow systemd[1]: Started Foo service for bar.
Sep 30 19:07:02 kptow systemd[1]: foo@bar.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 30 19:07:02 kptow systemd[1]: foo@bar.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 30 19:07:02 kptow systemd[1]: foo@bar.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The `%I` in the description gets replaced, but the `%i` in the ExecStart doesn't.  I've tried using `%i`/`%I`, but neither works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument to `ExecStart=` must be an absolute path to an executable. Substitutions are not accepted.

If you're just loading a bash script which then starts Node.js, you can do that explicitly:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/foo/%i/food
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the accepted answer, any file (including binaries) can be executed with substitution using `/usr/bin/env`:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env /path/to/foo/%i/food
```