# How to create a systemd "start all" template unit file from an upstart script with multiple services?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, upstart

I'm in the process of migrating all custom upstart scripts to systemd. I've come across a script that utilizes multiple services. I cannot figure out the proper syntax to handle this, or if I need to just create separate `.service` unit files for each. Is this possible for templating? The [SystemD Unit Documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) doesn't give me much information, except for how to create a template file (appending `@` to the name), and how to use `%i` to signify an instance.

The original upstart `dealer-start-all.conf`

```
console log
start on dealer-start
script
    declare -a dealers=("TimeZone" "Timeout" "Inquiry" "Refuse")

    for type in "${dealers[@]}"
    do
        if initctl list | grep "^dealer ($type)"
        then
            stop dealer type=$type
        fi
        start dealer type=$type
        echo "dealer$type started"
    done
end script
```

The other part of it, `dealer.conf`, should be pretty cut and dry by using `%i` in the `ExecStart` portion, like:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/dealer%i.php`

```
console log

instance $type

stop on dealer-stop

script
        sudo -u root php -f /path/to/dealer$type.php
end script

post-stop script

if [ -z "$UPSTART_STOP_EVENTS" ]
    then
        echo "dealer$type stopped at `date +"%F %T.%N"` Run 'initctl emit dealer-stop' then 'initctl emit dealer-start' on `hostname` to get it running again." | mail -s "dealer$type Stopped" alerts@myemail.com
    else
        echo "dealer$type was manually stopped at `date +"%F %T"`."
fi
end script
```

I just don't understand how to translate the array in the first one into a systemd version? Should I break these up into individual unit files? If so, then that's not a problem and can be easily done. I'm just unsure of syntax (if it exists) to do what the first one is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The systemd unit template **is a template**. You aren't going to put the array in it. Rather you're going to *instantiate* it for each instance you want, e.g.:

```
systemctl enable dealer@TimeZone
systemctl enable dealer@Timeout
...
```

Where `%i` appears in the template will be replaced with what you specified.

You also [can't use `%i` in the binary name](https://serverfault.com/a/806464/126632) in `ExecStart=`. It must be a path that exists, and `%i` used in its arguments. For example:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/dealer%i.php
```

Comment: Thank you. I had the /usr/bin/php portion, but forgot to type it in my question. I'll try this out and come back to accept.

Comment: I tried to enable one with `systemctl enable dealer@TimeZone`, and received an error: "The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequredBy, Also, Alias settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).

Comment: @IRGeekSauce Well that's a completely unrelated issue.

Comment: Added `[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target` and no error that time. Now back to the original task at hand.

Comment: I got that to work. I added a `dealers.target` file with `Requires=dealer-names-here`. Still not completely sure about all this, but this at least answered by initial question. Thank you for your help.